# Error while using the load class from Java to import property file

Tags: java

I've seen several examples of reading a properties file, but I can't seem to get it to work, am I missing a "load" method/class? Even the import does not work.

Please see attached image for more infomation:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wPq1.png)

Comment: Your class ```Properties``` is equals to ```Properties``` from ```java.util.lang```. I would recommend to change it and try again

Comment: precisely that! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming your class `Properties` is shadowing [`java.util.Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). You either need to rename your class to something like `MyProperties`, or qualify each access to `java.util.Properties` and remove the import.

```
private static java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
```

Comment: that also changes the return type, I'll just change the class name, thank you!

Comment: @notPercival No problem.